# react error: Target container is not a DOM element, (not using redux)

Tags: reactjs, components

For my react page, this is some code for our index page, and it works completely fine:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('reactEntry'),
);
```

and in index.html:

```
<div id="reactEntry" style="text-align: center;">
    Loading ...
</div>
```

but we have a similar implementation for another page, called editor:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Editor />,
    document.getElementById("Editor")
  );

<div id="Editor" style="text-align: center;">
    Loading ...
</div>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './newCharlaBots/js/main.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/newCharlaBots/static/js/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // Test for js or jsx files
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        // Exclude external modules from loader tests
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
        },
        //loaders: [{test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel']},{test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']}]
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

In this editor page, we get the error, "Target container is not a DOM element". I've tried looking at many StackOverflow posts but can't figure out what is the issue - does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of the react js script tag.
I hope this answer is helpful.

```html
<script>
  console.log("script #1:", document.getElementById("Editor")); // null
</script>
<div id="Editor" style="text-align: center;">
    Loading ...
</div>
<script>
  console.log("script #2:", document.getElementById("Editor")); // <div id="Editor" ...
</script>
```